# Viewing changes and crashing in Xcode 4.3 with SVN repository

Tags: xcode, svn

I am a new user to the subversion tool, I was trying to access revision changes from xcode 4.3 in the SVN repository. The path to the SVN was given correctly and also authentication details in the "username" and "password" sections of the top row in "Repositories" section in "Organizer" window. But after I select an application from repository and click "view changes" in the down window of the xcode organizer, the xcode immediately crashes. I have given a correct username and password of SCM to connect. I would be glad to know what could be the possible problems.